# A problem about convergence of anomalous integrals with vector norm

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, normed-spaces

**Background**: Let $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies:

$$
\max \left\{ \left| \mathbf{x}_1 \right|,\left| \mathbf{x}_2 \right|,\cdots ,\left| \mathbf{x}_N \right| \right\} <1,
$$

$p\in \mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbf{I}: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies

$$
\mathbf{I}\left( \mathbf{x} \right) =\int_0^{+\infty}{\frac{\lambda \left( p \right)}{p}}\lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert _{p}^{p}dp,
$$

where $\lambda :\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satifies

$$
\forall p\in [0,+\infty), \lambda(p)>0,
$$

and

$$
\int_0^{+\infty}{\lambda \left( p \right) dp}=1.
$$

---

**Question**: Does there exists some conditions, under which will $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}}\mathbf{I}\left( \mathbf{x} \right) $ converge? Can you give some examples?

Comment: This is not enough information to determine convergence. For example if $$\lambda(p)\sim \frac{1}{1+p^2}$$ this would always diverge. But if instead $\lambda(p)$ were Schwartz or at least exponential decay or better, we may have some actual conditions for convergence.

Comment: Thank you so much for your tips! Could you please give me an example convergence analysis such as when $\lambda(p)$ is exponential decaying and the corresponding closed-form result of the above-mentioned partial derivative? @NinadMunshi

Comment: I don't think your conditions on $\lambda$ are enough to even make $I$ well defined, let alone it's derivatives: There's a singularity at 0 introduced by the factor $1/p$, while if $\| x\|_p>1$ there's also the issue of $\|x\|_p^p$ growing exponentially (like $\| x\|_\infty^p$) as $p\to \infty$.

Comment: I see that there's now a condition that takes care of the issues at $\infty$; however, there's still the matter of the singularity at $p=0$: The quantity $\| x\|_p^p$, as $p\to 0$, tends to the number of nonzero entries of $x$, so unless $x=0$ the integral defining $I$ still might not converge if $\lambda$ doesn't vanish at $0$ in some way.